# The following file could not be created since it already exists. Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I faced with the next problem: when I create a new project, I see such warnings:

> The following file could not be created since it already exists:
>   build.gradle
>
> The following file could not be created since it already exists:
>   .gitignore
>
> The following file could not be created since it already exists:
>   settings.gradle
>
> The following file could not be created since it already exists:
>   gradle-wrapper.jar
>
> The following file could not be created since it already exists:
>   gradle-wrapper.properties
>
> If you proceed the resulting project may not compile or not work as
>   intended.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Did you try using/pointing to separate storage (folder) location for the project while creating project?

Answer (score -2):

I set a different folder as location and it worked without emitting a warning.